# Meta Pixel with GTM: Error - Standard Event Tag Firing Twice

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

I'm having issues setting up conversion tracking for registration with the Facebook Pixel on Google Tag Manager.

Here's how I currently have it set up:

1. **Facebook Pixel PageView tag to fire on some page views.** Reason being is our domain is used across several conferences and we differentiate each conference by adding a unique name after /. So the trigger is based on Page URL contains "/NAME".
2. **Facebook Pixel CompleteRegistration tag to fire on a custom even**t, again based on Page URL contains "/NAME".

The Meta Pixel helper keeps showing me the below error:

"The Facebook pixel activated 2 times on this web page, which can cause errors in your event tracking."

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzuFH.png

I tried modifying the conversion tracking using custom HTML instead with the below code:

```
<script>
  fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration')
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=606271094455493&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
```

I'm still getting the same error about this pixel being activated 2 times on the web page.

Comment: If you pause this tag. Will there still any `CompleteRegistration` fires?

Comment: Did you check the trigger in GTM. Is it actually firing twice? Log something to the console in that tag and see if it logs twice.